# Show div using onclick on an a tag

Tags: javascript, css

i try to show my div using  onclick but my funciton doesnt run when i click it
  here is my code

```
     <script> 
       function BxhNam() {
         document.getElementById("#Top5").style.display = "block";
     }
     </script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-item" onclick="return BxhNam();">Theo Năm</a>
<div id="Top5" style="display:none">
 <span>Content</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove hashtag from js `document.getElementById('Top5').style.display='block';` ... Why you put hashtag at all? Remove `href` from `a`, too... Why you don't use `<input type="button" onclick="BhxNum" value="Theo Nam" />`

Comment: it work man tks

Answer (score 2):

The 'getElementById()' method returns the element that has the ID attribute with the specified value. When you want to select an element with js selector by id you just must set an id with same id that was set as attribute(id) in html.
for select element by id "Top5" :

```
document.getElementById("Top5")
```

and in you code :

```
<script> 
     function BxhNam() {
         document.getElementById("Top5").style.display = "block";
     }
</script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-item" onclick="return BxhNam();">Theo Năm</a>
<div id="Top5" style="display:none">
  <span>Content</span>
</div>
```